# The current identity does not have write access to the 'Temporary ASP.NET Files' directory

Tags: asp.net

I keep receiving this error in my ASP.NET web app (below).  I give the Network Service account rights to the specified folder, it runs fine for a while, but then within a day or two the error reoccurs, as the Network Service account has been removed from the rights for the folder.  Adding it again fixes it, but why does it keep reocurring?

Could it be anything to do with using Interop components (such as WMI)?

Here's the full error:

```
Server Error in '/DriveMonitor' Application.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.

Source Error: 

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.  

Stack Trace: 


[HttpException (0x80004005): The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.SetUpCodegenDirectory(CompilationSection compilationSection) +8918190
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags) +152

[HttpException (0x80004005): The current identity (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE) does not have write access to 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files'.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +8890735
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +85
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +259
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your machine in  a domain? It could be group policy messing it up.

In my situation there was security directive to disable the ASPNET account.

It caused a generic Service Unavailable error which took a while to figure out.

Comment: Yeah it's on a domain - I think you're right, it may be something to do with that.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would also look to see if the server has Cisco Security agent installed (i think that is the name).  We had a similar issue where no matter what we did permission wise we could not get the network service access to the shadow copy folder and it turned out to be the Cisco security agent denying access to the folder.

Comment: Thanks - we don't have Cisco Security Agent, but it may be another security app that's the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add permissions.  Just change the TEMP directory for ASP.NET in your web.config file!

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" tempDirectory="c:\temp" />
  ...
</system.web>
```